# Change input value with attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have data-right-answer which keep the right answer, if the answers right i should change border color, if not i should write the right answer in input value, i can not imagine how i should to do it with attribute.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
btn.addEventListener("click", checkInputs);

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

function checkInputs(){
 for( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ){
  if( inputs[i].getAttribute("data-right-answer") == inputs[i].value ){
   inputs[i].style.border = "1px solid green";
  } else{
   // inputs[i].value = getAttribute("data-right-answer");
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" data-right-answer="Lolik">
<input type="text" data-right-answer="Lolik">
<input type="text" data-right-answer="Lolik">
<input type="text" data-right-answer="Lolik">
<input type="text" data-right-answer="Lolik">
<button id="myBtn">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot to get the attribute value in the else condition.

`inputs[i].value = inputs[i].getAttribute("data-right-answer");`

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
btn.addEventListener("click", checkInputs);

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

function checkInputs(){
 for( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ){
  if( inputs[i].getAttribute("data-right-answer") == inputs[i].value ){
   inputs[i].style.border = "1px solid green";
  } else{
   inputs[i].value = inputs[i].getAttribute("data-right-answer");
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" data-right-answer="Lolik">
<input type="text" data-right-answer="Lolik">
<input type="text" data-right-answer="Lolik">
<input type="text" data-right-answer="Lolik">
<input type="text" data-right-answer="Lolik">
<button id="myBtn">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

inputs[i].dataset.rightAnswer => this will capture the right answer from the "data-" attribute. :D

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
btn.addEventListener("click", checkInputs);

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

function checkInputs(){
 for( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ){
  if( inputs[i].dataset.rightAnswer == inputs[i].value ){
   inputs[i].style.border = "1px solid green";
  } else{
      inputs[i].value = inputs[i].dataset.rightAnswer;
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" data-right-answer="Lolik">
<input type="text" data-right-answer="Lolik">
<input type="text" data-right-answer="Lolik">
<input type="text" data-right-answer="Lolik">
<input type="text" data-right-answer="Lolik">
<button id="myBtn">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#myBtn').click(function(){
$('input').each(function(){
 if($(this).attr('data-right-answer')==$(this).val())
 {
 $(this).css('border','1px solid green')
 }
else{
 if($(this).val()!='')
 {
   $(this).val($(this).attr('data-right-answer'))
 }
}
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-right-answer="Lolik">
<input type="text" data-right-answer="Lolik">
<input type="text" data-right-answer="Lolik">
<input type="text" data-right-answer="Lolik">
<input type="text" data-right-answer="Lolik">
<button id="myBtn">Start</button>
```